# Populating child property with Entity Framework SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

Given the following POCO Code First Entities

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerTitle { get; set; }
    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   ...
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }

   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Using linq you can get the Orders filled in by using the Include property as in

```
var cust = (from cust in context.Customer
            where cust.CustomerId == 1
            select cust)
            .Include(ord => ord.Orders)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am trying to get the same result using paramaterised sql, using

```
        Customer co =  context.Customer.SqlQuery(
                    @"select [Customer].[CustomerId], 
                             ...
                             [Order].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
                             ...
                            from Customer join Order on Customer.CustomerId = Order.CustomerId where Customer.CustomerId = @custid", sqlParm)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I get the Orders in co.Orders to be populated with the above command, it seems like I can't use the Include statement with SqlQuery. This is a very simplified example for illustrative purposes only, the actual queries will be more involved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not possible at all. Direct SQL execution doesn't offer filling of navigation properties and you really can't use Include. You must execute two separate SQL queries to get `Cutomer` and her `Orders`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following class structure as workaround:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    private int _customerId;
    private int CustomerId { get { return _customerId; } set { Customer.CustomerId = _customerId = value; } }
    public Order()
    {
        Customer = new Customer();
    }
}
```

In this case you don't need to run the query twice, and the following query would give the order with customer:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<Order>(
    "select cu.CustomerId, ord.OrderId from Orders ord join Customer cu on cu.CustomerId=ord.CustomerId")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to access the related member before the using is closed.

```
public static Customer GetCustomer (int custid)
{
Customer co = null;

using (var context = new YourEntities())
{
    // your code
    co =  context.Customer.SqlQuery(
    @"select [Customer].[CustomerId], 
    ...
    [Order].[OrderId] AS [OrderId], 
    ...
    from Customer join Order on Customer.CustomerId = Order.CustomerId where Customer.CustomerId = @custid", sqlParm)
    .FirstOrDefault();


    // my addition
    // cause lazy loading of Orders before closing the using
    ICollection<Order> orders = co.Orders;

    }

    // can access co.Orders after return.
    return (co);
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() causes the query to be executed, so this is actually equal to executing two queries