# EF 6.1.3 and child property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I have this mvc controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
    var c = _hc.Countries.Where(l => l.Code.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
    var customers = _hc.Customers.Where(h => h.Country.Code.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    foreach (var h in customers)
        h.Country = c;

    return View(customers);
}
```

Everything works, but I just want the `Customer.Country.Code` to have a value. And since this one lists for all customers with the same country...

Same for when I use a raw `SqlQuery` (because of the geolocation stuff)

```
var customers = _hc.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>(@"
                SELECT customers.*, countries.code
                FROM [dbo].customers
                inner join countries on customers.countryid = countries.id
                where geography::Point(50.436912, 5.972050, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326)) <= 25000").ToList();
```

I have the countryid in the customer object, because that is the Foreign Key. And have seen some extension method which you could use to include other data. But according to my intellisens, it's not availble. Probably something easy. But too hard for a friday afternoon (for me).

Comment: In order to use the Include() extension method you need to be using System.Data.Entity. See [DbExtensions.Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Is Include the best/preferred way?

Comment: It's a way, and I have used it in the past. The other alternative I can think of might be projections, but that may be more relevant if you have a separate service layer and are using something like Automapper - see [Automapper Projections](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the Include() extension method you need to add the following:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

See [DbExtensions.Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)

Example usage:

```
var customers = _hc.Customers
    .Include(h => h.Country)
    .Where(h => h.Country.Code.Equals(country, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Already found this thanks to @Cal279. Now up to the next thing: The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Code'

Comment: @JPHellemons Yeah, I thought I would post it as an answer to make it more clear what's going on. Have updated the above to remove 'Code' in the include.

Comment: Thanks. Would the include also work for raw sql like my second example? Will try in a few minutes.

Comment: Sorry, not sure. I've hardly ever used .SqlQuery()

Comment: This would indicate that it would not - [Populating child property with Entity Framework SqlQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822072/populating-child-property-with-entity-framework-sqlquery)